# Adding functionality to existing thread-safe class

Tags: java, multithreading

For below code,

```
public class ListHelper<E>{
   public List<E> list = 
               Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<E>());
   .....
   public synchronized  boolean putIfAbsent(E x){
      boolean absent = !list.contains(x);
      if(absent){
          list.add(x);
      }      
   }
}
```

[Java author](https://www.amazon.ca/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Tim-Peierls-ebook/dp/B004V9OA84/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1/137-6517246-3281829) says,

> For each mutable state variable that may be accessed by more than one thread, all accesses to that variable must be performed with the same lock held.

On performing `putIfAbsent` operation, Is this(above) the cause for failure in thread safety?

Comment: If `list` is `public`, you will need to make it `final` in order to prevent it from being altered by any unsafe code.

Comment: @4castle even if it's final it can be modified (add/remove elements)

Comment: @alfasin Right, but the `Collections.synchronizedList` will make those modifications thread-safe.

Comment: but it won't help when calling `putIfAbsent` the way it's implemented above, you might end up adding the same element twice since the check `!list.contains(x)` and the `list.add(x)` are not synchronized on the list object, which means that you might call ` !list.contains(x)` get false, someone else will call `list.add(x)` with the same object and then you'll call `list.add(x)` as well

Comment: @4castle Scope outside of `ListHelper` class should not use `list` as lock.

Answer (score 1):

It's the wrong lock (syncs on `ListHelper` instead of on `list`), further, since `list` is published as public - it's accessible to anyone with a pointer to the `ListHelper` object.

Make it private and make sure no one can access it directly (other then through the synchronized methods you'll provide) and make sure you're syncing when performing read as well - and you should be golden.

Another way to do it is to provide an unmodifiable copy of the list to the reader.

Comment: `list` being public can be used as a lock by clients of `ListHelper` , is a problem. But making `list` private still has the problem of wrong lock on `putIfAbsent`. Isn't `synchronized(list)` the correct lock with `list` as private?

Comment: nope: if you don't hand off the list to your clients and you're the only one that is performing actions on it, then, if you do as I suggested, you can use a "normal" list - you don't have to have a synchronized one!

Comment: There are only two things you want to make sure of: 1. that the `contains()` check and `list.add()` are done as an atomic action. 2. when you're reading from the list it's synchronized on the same object as when you're writing into the list. That holds true assuming you're not allowing the clients to have direct access to the original list (just to a copy).

Comment: Further, handing the clients the list and asking them to sync on it when performing actions is bad practice - it's an invitation for them to shoot themselves in the foot... I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: For your point: *when you're reading from the list it's synchronized on the same object*. In the above code, It's not synchornized on same object `list`, but instead synchronized on `this`. Java author also says the same.

Comment: @overexchange true, which is why I wrote: "and make sure you're syncing when performing read as well" - if he syncs on the same `ListHelper` object during read he's good (either that or create another copy for read). And then, by the way, there's no reason to declare the list as `sunchronizedList` ;)

Comment: Am saying that, if he syncs on the same `ListHelper` object during read(`list.contains(x)`) he's not good. This is problem code

Comment: The sync in the method signature makes sure that both actions are synced on `ListHelper` object which makes it fine as long as reads are handled the same way.

Comment: Read section *4.4.1 client side locking* by java author. It says, *Client-side locking entails guarding client code that uses some object X with the lock X uses to guard its own state.*

Comment: @overexchange I'm not clear on what you're trying to say

Comment: `putIfAbsent` should be locked by `list` but not by `ListHelper` type object

Comment: True, that's another option which can fix the issue (and then you shouldn't synchronize the method!)

Comment: That's the only option

Comment: No it's not! further, there's still an issue of making `list` public, which means it can be accessed somewhere else. @brian-goetz is the chief architect of java and his book is excellent, unfortunately I can only guess that he didn't attend this issue (of `list` being public) since he was treating it as a "toy example" in which he wanted to show the problematic issues that might occur when you're syncing on the wrong object while trying to perform an atomic operation.

Comment: `list` being public is definitely an issue, which your answer talks, but not related to my query. My query is, how to make `putIfAbsent` operation thread safe? This is why i did not vote your answer

Comment: and my answer was: if you restrict all accesses to list (all access is done through `ListHelper` object), you don't expose `list` and make sure that read operations are also synched on the same `ListHelper` object - you're good. The fact that there's another valid answer doesn't mean that this one isn't ;)

Comment: The nice thing about this answer is that it removes the requirement to declare list as `synchronizedList` which makes the operations on it much faster. Further, AFAIK it is not recommended to use `Collections.synchronizedList`, what you want to use instead is `copyonwritearraylist` because it performs better on traversal.

Comment: Question is about adding on functionality to existing thread-safe class

Comment: And the answer answers just that. The best advise I can give you as engineer to engineer: *never* stick to a specific solution, don't fall in love with your solution, always look for other solutions, always try to find the cons in your solution. If you'll do it - you'll become a good engineer!

Comment: Last comment: remember that all the read/writes to `list` should sync on the same object, that said - it doesn't necessarily have to be `list` - it can be any other object!